# Need Oracle sql to list records where for a key, specific value is paired with other values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in a table Tab like this :

```
DEPT    ROLE
-------------    
100     Sell
101 Admin
102 Admin
102 Staff
103 Admin
103 Staff
103 Sell
104 FRQ
104 Staff
104 Sell
105 Admin
105 INT
105 Sell
```

I need to list only DEPTs where Admin is appearing with at least one other role but not Admin alone or not any other DEPT where Admin is not present.
For Example : 102, 103,105 are desired results but 100,101,104 are filtered out.

Could you please assist me in this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need something. Did you try something?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT YT.DEPT
FROM   YOUR_TABLE YT
       JOIN
         YOUR_TABLE ADM ON ADM.DEPT = YT.DEPT
WHERE  ADM.ROLE = 'Admin'
AND    YT.ROLE != 'Admin'
```

Basically I used inner join to filter depts having no `'Admin'` roles and filtered `'Admin'` roles from this resultset.

Comment: You should probably change the column list to DISTINCT YT.Dept instead of YT.*

Comment: Yea, sure, if only dept ids are needed. Thanks

Comment: It works. Thank You "that young man" and "Tom". Just curious if it possible to do it by using some analytical function rank , count ?

Comment: Well, of course it is. It'd just look pretty messy. You will need sort clause that ranks rows with `ROLE = 'Admin'` higher or lower. Then you can use [FIRST_VALUE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/first-value-and-last-value-analytic-functions#first-value). `FIRST_VALUE(ROLE) OVER(PARTITION BY DEPT ORDER BY DECODE(ROLE, 'Admin', 1, 2))` should be `'Admin'` and `FIRST_VALUE(ROLE) OVER(PARTITION BY DEPT ORDER BY DECODE(ROLE, 'Admin', 2, 1))` should not be `'Admin'`. I warned you.

Answer (score 1):

```
select DEPT
from T
group by DEPT
having
        count(case when ROLE  = 'Admin' then 1 end) > 0
    and count(case when ROLE <> 'Admin' then 1 end) > 0
```

You can certainly use an inner join for simple conditions. This is the more general approach that's adaptable if the query needs to change. By eliminating the join(s) it's likely to be faster as well.

Comment: Thanks shant00. That's also nice way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way that will give you depts that have more than one role which includes the role admin

```
SELECT a.DEPT
from TEST a
join (select DEPT from TEST group by DEPT having count(*) > 1) b on a.id = b.id and a.ROLE = 'ADMIN'
```